# Quicksort in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, quicksort

I am trying to do a quicksort using LISP but I am having trouble with my functions output.

```
(defun qsort (L)
   (cond
   ((null L) nil)
   (t(append
      (qsort (list< (car L) (cdr L)))
      (cons (car L) nil)
      (qsort (list>= (car L) (cdr L)))))))

(defun list< (a b)
    (cond
    (( or(null a)(null b) nil))
    (( < a (car b)) (list< a (cdr b)))
    (t(cons (car b) (list< a (cdr b))))))

(defun list>= (a b)
    (cond
    (( or( null a)(null b) nil))
    (( >= a (car b)) (list> a (cdr b)))
    (t(cons (car b) (list> a (cdr b))))))
```

My problem being when *list<* and *list>=* finish the list always ends with a .T. For instance:

```
> (list< '4 '(1 5 3 8 2))
Entering: LIST<, Argument list: (4 (1 5 3 8 2))
 Entering: LIST<, Argument list: (4 (5 3 8 2))
  Entering: LIST<, Argument list: (4 (3 8 2))
   Entering: LIST<, Argument list: (4 (8 2))
    Entering: LIST<, Argument list: (4 (2))
     Entering: LIST<, Argument list: (4 NIL)
     Exiting: LIST<, Value: T
    Exiting: LIST<, Value: (2 . T)
   Exiting: LIST<, Value: (2 . T)
  Exiting: LIST<, Value: (3 2 . T)
 Exiting: LIST<, Value: (3 2 . T)
Exiting: LIST<, Value: (1 3 2 . T)
(1 3 2 . T)
```

Why is *(4 NIL)* evaluating as T?

Comment: I always point out the [Sheep Trick from _The Pitmanual_](http://www.maclisp.info/pitmanual/funnies.html#sheep_trick) when quicksort in Common Lisp comes up.

Comment: Downvoted for not formatting the source code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem with `list<`, and also with `list>=`, lies on `((or ( null a)(null b) nil))`, it should be `(( or( null a)(null b)) nil)`. Note `nil` was moved outside of the condition to be the returned value.

Furthermore, on the definition of `list>=` you are calling `list>`, but I'm positive you meant `list>=` instead.

I would also suggest some [indentation](http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html) to address the legibility of lisp, like follows

```
(defun qsort (L)
  (cond
    ((null L) nil)
    (t
      (append
        (qsort (list< (car L) (cdr L)))
        (cons (car L) nil) 
        (qsort (list>= (car L) (cdr L)))))))

(defun list< (a b)
  (cond
    ((or (null a) (null b)) nil)
    ((< a (car b)) (list< a (cdr b)))
    (t (cons (car b) (list< a (cdr b))))))

(defun list>= (a b)
  (cond
    ((or (null a) (null b)) nil)
    ((>= a (car b)) (list>= a (cdr b)))
    (t (cons (car b) (list>= a (cdr b))))))
```

Some testing follows:

```
(list< '4 '(1 5 3 8 2))
=> (1 3 2)

(list>= '4 '(1 5 3 8 2))
=> (5 8)

(qsort '(1 5 3 8 2))
=> (1 2 3 5 8)
```

Comment: The first I thing I do when I have problem in LISP is go over my parenthesis and I still missed it and yes I just forgot the = when writing it on here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Lisp has different kinds of collections. I think sort a list using quick-sort is not a good choice. In the implementation of STL in C++, the sorting method of list is merge-sort. I have tried to implement a 3-way quick-sort using the collections of array.

```
(defun quick-sort (arr start end)
  "Quick sort body"
  (if (< start end)
  (let ((n-pair (partition arr start end)))
  (quick-sort arr start (car n-pair))
  (quick-sort arr (cdr n-pair) end))
))

(defun partition (arr start end)
 "Partition according to pivot."
 (let ((pivot (aref arr start)) (cur start))
 (loop while (<= start end) do
  (cond
    ((< pivot (aref arr start)) ; pivot < arr[start], swap with arr[end]
     (swap arr start end) (decf end))
    ((> pivot (aref arr start)) ; pivot > arr[start], swap with arr[start]
     (swap arr cur start) (incf cur) (incf start))
    (t                          ; otherwise
     (incf start))))
    (cons (decf cur) start)))

(defun swap (arr i j)
 "Swap element of arr"
 (let ((tmp (aref arr i)))
 (setf (aref arr i) (aref arr j))
 (setf (aref arr j) tmp)))
```

Comment: `Swap` is called `rotatef` and part of the standard.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun quick (list)
  (when (< = (length list) 1) (return-from quick list))
  (let ((pivot (car list)) (rest (cdr list)) (less nil) (greater nil))
    (loop for i in rest do
      (if (< i pivot) (push i less) (push i greater)))
    (append (quick less) (list pivot) (quick greater))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to change the code of liya babu/Will Ness like this:

```
(defun quick (list)
  (if (null list) nil
      (let ((pivot (first list)) (less nil) (greater nil))
        (dolist (i (rest list))
          (if (< i pivot) (push i less) (push i greater)))
        (append (quick less) (list pivot) (quick greater)))))
```

Although just slightly edited I find it both more lispy and more succinct.

Comment: Or just use `(when list ...)`. Also, using `let`, initializing to `nil` is 'implicit'.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in the program.  The corrected program is:

```
(defun qsort (L)
   (cond
   ((null L) nil)
   (t (append
      (qsort (list< (car L) (cdr L)))
      (cons (car L) nil)
      (qsort (list>= (car L) (cdr L)))))))

(defun list< (a b)
    (cond
    (( or (null a) (null b)) nil)
    (( < a (car b)) (list< a (cdr b)))
    (t (cons (car b) (list< a (cdr b))))))

(defun list>= (a b)
    (cond
    (( or ( null a)(null b)) nil)
    (( >= a (car b)) (list>= a (cdr b)))
    (t (cons (car b) (list>= a (cdr b))))))
```

Answer (score -1):

This should also work:

```
(defun qsort (l)
  (cond
   ((null l) nil)
   (t (append
       (qsort (car(list<> (car l)(cdr l))))
       (cons (car l) nil)
       (qsort (cadr(list<> (car l)(cdr l))))))))

(defun list<> (a b &optional rl rr)
    (cond
     ((null b) (list rl rr))
     ((<=(car b)a) (list<> a (cdr b) (cons (car b) rl) rr))
     (t (list<> a (cdr b)rl (cons (car b) rr)))))

(setq l (loop for j from 1 to 20 append (list(random 100))))
(qsort l)
;=> (86 99 9 31 66 58 57 43 48 21 51 0 32 69 39 47 59 76 69 23)
;=> (0 9 21 23 31 32 39 43 47 48 51 57 58 59 66 69 69 76 86 99)
```